# Menu doesn't appear in custom toolbar layout

Tags: android

I've seen a tutorial video that the guy create custom layout for toolbar and set manu to that toolbar ant that worked fine 
I did the same thing but menu didn't appear in my custom toolbar !!
This is my code. Do you know where is the problem ?

This is toolbar layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:minWidth="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0 Item Selected"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

This is main activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is my main activity that handles the toolbar and menu

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar toolbar ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
}
```

Comment: The `android:id` on the `<include>` overrides the `android:id` on the root `View` in the included layout, so your `Toolbar` is ending up with ID `include`. That means that `findViewById(R.id.toolbar)` is returning null, so nothing is set as the `ActionBar`, and the menu is never set up. Either remove that `android:id` on the `<include>`, or change the `findViewById()` call to pass `R.id.include` instead.

Comment: It works. I deleted include id . tnx

Answer (score 1):

you are using the wrong ID for calling it in the findViewByID(). please make sure you need only one. Make changes like this.

in your main activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

in your main activity class

```
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```